# How do i compare a byte[] to string?

Tags: c#, string, arrays

I want to compare the first few bytes in byte[] with a string. How can i do this?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You must know the encoding of the byte array to properly compare them.

For example, if you know your byte array is made of UTF-8 bytes, then you can create a string from the byte array:

```
System.Text.UTF8Encoding enc = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
string s = enc.GetString(originalBytes);
```

Now you can compare string s to your other string.

Conversely, if you want to compare just the first few bytes, you can convert the string into a UTF8 byte array:

```
System.Text.UTF8Encoding enc = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
byte[] b = enc.GetBytes(originalString);
```

Now you can compare byte array b to your other byte array.

There are several other encoding objects for ASCII, Unicode, etc.   [See the MSDN page here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx)

Comment: Isn't it more efficient to compare bytes instead of Strings?!

Comment: @Josh: What do you think string comparison is? Worrying about this is probably a microoptimization.

Comment: I meant cast, not compare.  My bad.

Comment: @Josh - Funny! As soon as I wrote my answer, I had exactly the same question as you did! (and in my head, it had a "?!" too - no joke!)

Answer (score 1):

use

```
byte [] fromString = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("helloworld");
```